# Can I change the DPI of an Android device and have it fully take effect without a reboot?

Tags: android, screen, android-4.4-kitkat, dpi

I'd like to be able to dynamically change the DPI of a device I'm using for development. It's running Android Kit-Kat 4.4.4.

I currently use the WindowManagerService (setForcedDisplayDensity) to set the DPI from code. This is equivalent, I believe, to using "wm density " from shell (where N is the desired DPI). I've verified that the DPI value gets set (by reading the value afterwards e.g. by using "wm density"), and that, indeed, the Android platform and apps respond to the DPI. Partially, at least.

The problem I have is that the Android status bar (at the top of the screen) doesn't change with changing DPI; it only respects the initial DPI on boot.

If, for example, my initial DPI is 240 and I change it to 360, "wm density" will indicate that the DPI is currently 360, any open apps will alter accordingly, but the status bar will remain unchanged. If I then reboot the device, the DPI will still be 360 and the status bar will have changed to match the new DPI setting.

> Is there a way to dynamically and programmatically change the DPI without a reboot in Android Kit-Kat? If not, is it possible in Marshmallow?